# Why was my question regarding a launcher for Minecraft closed as off-topic?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I'm a bit confused. I understand that questions like "recommend best/fun/cool game" are not of much use. But questions with objective parameters should be IMO fine. My [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132955/replacement-of-multimc-for-minecraft-1-6-4) has been closed, but [question which is almost same](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81845/launcher-with-jar-changer) (MC launcher with specific parameters) is alright?

I'm a newbie here and probably missing something elementary (or my English is worse than I thought)...

EDIT:
So, if I understand correctly I'm supposed to describe what I'm using in MultiMC (pretty much everything) and just remove references from the Q. Isn't it a bit dumb, when I'm looking for MultiMC replacement to remove it from Q?

I was looking around and found more questions which are essentialy software (mods) recommendations (the answer is expected to be software and the questions specifies parameters of it):

[Is there a faster and more reliable way to install a mod?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96483/is-there-a-faster-and-more-reliable-way-to-install-a-mod)
[Is there an “inventory mod” that doesn't allow cheating?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/123917/is-there-an-inventory-mod-that-doesnt-allow-cheating)
[Is there a minecraft mod for wood cutting?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45244/is-there-a-minecraft-mod-for-wood-cutting)

After some more reading of MCF it seems that there is no replacement of MultiMC, I'm not sure if it's worth the time of rewriting my question, while still risking immediate closing of it - so effectively wasting my time (because rule[s] of what gets closed seems to be pretty non-specific)...

EDIT2:
I did my best in rewriting the orginal question. I'm still not sure if it's fine for this site.

Comment: I won't comment on the correctness or wrongness of this closure as off-topic, but I do think your question is a duplicate of the other question you linked.

Comment: No, it is not. It has some similar traits, but it certainly does not equal my question. Launcher with support for more main jars is not equal to completely separate instance folders, instance creation from GUI and so on...

Comment: Incidentally, the other question got closed now, too.  Slipped through the cracks, it did.

Comment: No, what you're supposed to do is tell us what *problem* MultiMC solved for you, and can't in the latest version.  Tell us what you're wanting to do, not what you used to do it.  As for your other examples, the first one describes his problem, and asks for solutions.  That's exactly what we want *you* to do.  The other two are mod recommendations, and I've voted to close them as such.

Comment: @fbueckert "*The other two are mod recommendations, and I've voted to close them as such.*" There is *no* blanket ban on mod recommendation questions (they are *not* off-topic simply because mods are mentioned as possible or preferable solutions by the OP), as per community consensus at the Arqade Meta posts, [Is “mod rec” really an umbrella category that we want to use?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6830/4797) and [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5548/4797)

Answer (score 3):

I'm the instigator of the closure.  The reason I voted to close is because your question, when you boil it down to its bare bones, is a software recommendation question.

You point at another piece of software, and request another piece of software that does the same thing, only for a different version of Minecraft.  And that makes any answer that gets provided subjective.  There's no way to definitively answer it, and answers are going to be nothing but, "Hey, try this program.  That might do the trick."  Voting on those answers isn't done on correctness; it might fit the bill, but maybe someone doesn't like that piece of software.  They'll downvote it because it's not what they use.  And the same with upvoting.

@GalacticNinja's comment about mod recommendations obscures the issue.  Straight mod recommendations that ask for certain criteria are also off topic, regardless of whether or not it's a mod.  The point about allowing mods is if the question has an underlying problem, we can re-word it to bring that problem to the forefront, and eliminate the request for mods entirely.  A mod can certainly be the answer to the question, but there doesn't need to be the assumption that only a mod can solve the problem.

If you can re-word your question so that it describes an actual problem that can be solved, I will happily vote to re-open.  Maybe something like, "I have several different instances of Minecraft. How can I easily launch the specific one I want, without having to dig through lots of folders?".  Any answers you get to that can then be judged on utility, rather than whether or not it meets the exact criteria of a different program.

I think the other question you mentioned has the exact same problems as yours, and I've voted to close it as well.

Comment: I think that when you boil it down to its bare bones, it's the reworded "problem" question you indicate.  OP might be OK with a solution involving arcane magic or something, but realistically it's going to be software ... explicitly specifying that software is needed doesn't really alter the issue at hand.

Comment: @MatthewRead All I'm seeing on that question is, "I want something exactly like MultiMC that works with the latest version of Minecraft."  That's a software recommendation, through and through.  Now, WHY does he need a newer version?  What problem is it solving for him now that it can't for the updated version?  That's the info we need for an acceptable question.

Comment: I thought I did describe it better in the last edit, but I can try to rewrite it - mainly remove the MultiMC references? However I'm afraid it's just word-splitting (<- not sure if I found the right translation) - I'd be just describing most of the MultiMC's features.

Comment: @monnef And that's the thing; you're not telling us what problem you're having.  All you're doing is listing the features that MultiMC has, and you want a replacement for it.  That's a straight up software recommendation.  If you can reword it to focus more on the problem you're facing, that might be something we can solve.  Why do you use MultiMC?  What does it do for you that it can't in the latest version of Minecraft?  Those would be acceptable in my books.

Comment: @monnef In other words, describe what you're trying to accomplish, and what is preventing you from accomplishing it. Then people can give answers that overcome the roadblock and accomplish the task. Their solutions might not be *exactly* what you originally assumed should solve the problem… but that's why you come here for expert advice. Users trying to solve your implied, underlying problem is why you were getting answers that were "don't bother trying to get something exactly like MultiMC; do this instead".